# Can I pass data to view if I use redirect in codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to pass data to a page to which I redirect my visitor.
is it possible or another way to pass data to view in redirect method.

> I have a contact page to which user input some fields and if form validation goes wrong then redirect user again to contact page with the data which he enter in contact form. when he redirect again to contact page then I want to show that data. Any good solution for this?

I use this function

```
redirect('/contact');
```

Comment: use CI form validation library to get this

Comment: m validating input data using CI validation but if validation goes wrong then i redirect user again to contact page

Comment: use `set_value` for retaining the data in form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways, you can pass values while redirecting the user.

**1. Using Sessions:**
Use session to pass data while redirecting. There is a special method in CodeIgniter to do it called `set_flashdata`

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('in',1);
redirect("home/index");
```

Now you may get in your index controller like

```
function index()
{
 $in = $this->session->flashdata('in');
  if($in==1)
  {

  }
}
```

> Remember this data will available only for redirect and lost on next
>   page request. If you need stable data then you can use URL with
>   parameter & GET `$this->input->get('param1')`

**2. Using Get values**

So in the controller you can have in one function :

```
$value=1;
redirect(base_url()."home/index/".$value);
```

And in the target function you can access the $value value like this :

```
$value= $this->uri->segment(3);   
if(!is_numeric($value))
{
  redirect();       
}else{
   if($value == 1){

   }
}
```

I put `segment(3)` because in your example `$value` is after 2 dashes. But if you have for example this link structure: `www.mydomain.com/subdomain/home/index/$value` you'll have to use `segment(4)`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass data using 'Codeigniter Flashdata' concept. It's simple.

Step 1: **Load session library at your controller class**.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Step 2: **Add flash data.**

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item','Test values');
```

Here, your redirection code. After redirection if you want that 'Flashdata value' use below code.

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

Print the above code you will get the data.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do simply like this

```
$array = ['name' => 'abc', 'email' => 'abc@gmail.com'];
$this->session->set_flashdata('arrayData', $array);

// You can use in view like this
$array = $this->session->flashdata('arrayData');
echo $msg['name']; // Output : abc
```